# Does Instinctive Flyby require the power to be charged?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, powers

The Young Green Dragon has the power *instictive flyby*:

> On an initiative of 10 + its initiative check, the dragon can use a free action to use *flyby attack*.

*flyby attack*:

> Flyby Attack • Recharge [5-6]

Does "Flyby Attack" need to be charged (and a charge expended) whenever "Instinctive Flyby" is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

The power *instinctive flyby* does not specifically mention that *flyby attack* can be used even if it's expended. In general, expended powers cannot be used again until they are recharged. In this case, *instinctive flyby* just allows the power to be used as a free action on a certain initiative order instead of spending an action on the dragon's main turn.